# Using value from one ng-repeat as part of another ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to build a table with dynamic number of columns and would like to use those column headers to then decide which attributes of an object to display. Below is what I would like to do, however it throws a parse error.  Any ideas?

```
<table class="table">

    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="th in tableHeaders">{{th}}</th>
    </thead>

    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
        <td>{{item.{{th}}}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**th array**

```
['column1', 'column2']
```

**item array**

```
[
    {column1:blah, column2:blah},
    {column1:blah2, column2:blah2}
]
```

**Update 1**
I tried using the following and I get a bunch of empty rows.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
<td ng-repeat="th in tableHeaders">{{item.$eval(th)}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? what you want to acheive?

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates it's own child scope, so `th` isn't accessible in that other `repeat` since it's out of scope.

Comment: The `th` variable is existing only in the `ng-repeat` block in its own `scope`. In the second ng-repeat you can use something like `tableHeaders[$index]` instead of `th`. But as I can see you are trying to access to the properties of item so there is maybe an eval() needed ?

Comment: how would you use eval() to accomplish this?

Comment: `$eval` evaluates expression from string... At time I was reading your question there wasnt the arrays present. Is there a problem to type them all in `<td>` blocks ? Because now what you get is many rows with only 1 column. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/npP6u/2/

Comment: I am trying to get a row for each item in items, and a column in that row for each tableHeader, and use that tableHeader value as the attribute I am displaying on the item.

Comment: @islander, the only problem with the fiddle is that you are using `<td>{{item.column2}}</td>`  the column2 value has to come from the tableHead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using the column definition from the headers. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7w8eB/)

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="th in tableHeaders">{{th}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td ng-repeat="col in tableHeaders">{{item[col]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If your column in tableHeaders is an object you can also do col.property. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dV9k7/)

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out in the comments, a `ng-repeat` creates its own child scope. So trying to reference a `th` later in the table isn't possible, unless it was a parent.

So what you need is an additional `ng-repeat`. on you actual `td` element. One repeat will take care of the `<tr>`, and the other one will loop over the number of objects in each of those rows.

Check out this [fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/npP6u/3/)

```
<table class="table">

    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="th in tableHeaders">{{th}}</th>
    </thead>

    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td ng-repeat="col in item">{{col}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This will work if he will have the objects in order. This wont work by column names. But also a good solution ;). If this is what he wants arrays should be enough.

Comment: that is getting close, but like @islander says it is a problem if the columns are in a different order on the object. Also if the object has extra columns they are still displayed.  http://jsfiddle.net/npP6u/6/